# Why is there a huge difference in speed between these regexes?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, performance

I was working on pulling a specific slice of information from a file a couple thousand lines of code long. My original regex was this:

```
re.findall('#+\s+Athstats\s+Radio\s+(\d+).+?(\d+)\s+nodes\s+allocated\(nodealloc\)\s+ (\d+)\s+nodes\s+deleted\(nodefree\)', source_string, re.DOTALL)
```

After I changed it to these:

```
re.findall('#+\s*Athstats\s*Radio\s*(\d).*?#+.*?(\d+)\s*nodes\s*allocated\(nodealloc\)', source_string, re.DOTALL)
re.findall('#+\s*Athstats\s*Radio\s*(\d).*?#+.*?(\d+)\s*nodes\s*deleted\(nodefree\)', source_string, re.DOTALL)
```

Things slowed down to a crawl... it was taking matters of seconds instead of micro/nano seconds! Why is this? I'm using Python 2.7 looking through a text file with a few thousands lines of text long.

Comment: Unbounded-length matches on unbounded character sets are dangerous. I'd strongly advise not doing them at all -- especially since it looks like the information involved in any single match should, in practice, be fairly close together.

Comment: The information it's searching through could be any character so an unbounded character makes sense. The separate pieces of information are about 10-50 lines apart.

Comment: Please, could you post a representative sample of your input data? (be precise with begining and end of lines in particular).

Comment: It's sensitive information to work, so I'm not actually able to post it. I was just wondering if there was something in the regexes themselves that would lead to the slow down. They are very similar and that much a speed difference was pretty surprising.

Comment: Even it is sensitive informations, it's no really a problem, it's easy to post a sample, you can change data and keep the same structure. Withtout seeing any data, all that I can notice is: `.*?#+.*?` that causes probably a catastrophic backtracking. But without data sample I can't find an efficient alternative.

Comment: If you know that they're not more than 15 lines apart, determine the maximum number of characters per line, multiply, and bound the maximum character count to that. That way you don't have to scan the entire rest of the file worst-case (every time you find something that looks like the part of the document _preceding_ such an unbounded mach). I fully agree with Casimir re: the immediate cause.

Comment: Is there a link to see how regexes actually go about finding a match? I guess I'm naïve about that.

Comment: The traditional, and fast, algorithm is the Thompson NFA. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson's_construction_algorithm and links (particularly, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_finite_automaton). Unfortunately, see http://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html for discussion of how Python, Perl, PHP, &c. use a far slower algorithm with far, far worse worst-case performance in order to allow support for backreferences.

Comment: ...for a full discussion including enough information to understand which regexes will and won't perform well using Python's implementation, see Mastering Regular Expressions, by Jeffrey Friedl. The first edition discussed Python's implementation specifically; the second did not; I'm not sure about the third.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the reference material! I will definitely need to look that up.

Answer (score 0):

Even it is sensitive informations, it's no really a problem, it's easy to post a sample, you can change data and keep the same structure. Withtout seeing any data, all that I can notice is: `.*?#+.*?` that causes probably a catastrophic backtracking. But without data sample I can't find an efficient alternative. –  Casimir et Hippolyte

...for a full discussion including enough information to understand which regexes will and won't perform well using Python's implementation, see Mastering Regular Expressions, by Jeffrey Friedl. The first edition discussed Python's implementation specifically; the second did not; I'm not sure about the third. –  Charles Duffy